# Problem with Update-alternatives for java

Tags: nativescript-vue

I try to setup nativescript-vue on linux by following steps on nativescript website. when I use this command

> sudo update-alternatives --config java

but have an error

> update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java

Please tell me how to fix this problem......

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java  path_to_java 1
```

In my case the path was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have java installed?
Check if you do by running `java -version` in the command line/terminal